# Bind named function to context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dom-events, event-binding

I have a named function like this

```
function handler(arg) {
  this.arg = arg;
}
```

Is there a way to bind context to this function?

I'm looking for something like this

```
function handler(arg) {
  this.arg = arg;
}.bind(this);
```

that will allow to call this function in any context, but it will always use bound context.

For example I have another function (in vendor code, that I can't edit):

```
addEventListener(callback) {
   callback(currentArg);
}
```

where I will pass handler and it will be executed with bound context.

Comment: looks like a classic use case for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: I believe if you declare `handler =  handler.bind(this)` in another context, say another function it will bind to handlers 'this' to that context .

Comment: Can you give more details? Like where you want to use this and why?

Comment: Use `addEventListener(handler.bind(this))`

Comment: addEventListener(handler.bind(this)) is generally good advice, but if there is some other function like removeEventListener - it is impossible to perform removeEventListener(handler.bind(this))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where and how you are going to use it but you can use a function expression instead of function deceleration:

```
 var handler = function handler(arg) {
  this.arg = arg;
}.bind(this)
```

Or just use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will use a lexical context for `this`:

```
var handler = (arg) => {...}
```

Comment: Thats ok, thanks. Just for curious how do you think is it realy impossible to solve this via named functions and it could be done only by anonymous?

Comment: it doesn't have to be anonymous, you can (and should!) name these functions (I've updated my answer to reflect this). but it has to be a function expression (on the right side of the equal sign). with function declarations you can't reassign to that label, after all `bind` will return a new function instance.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

According to this definition you can do the following

```
function handler(arg) {
  this.arg = arg;
}

var newFunc = handler.bind(newContext,arg);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to avoid context change, you can use arrow function:

```
handler = (arg) => {
    this.arg = arg;
};
```

Comment: You cannot bind an arrow function. It will always be called with the context in which it was defined but the questions says `call this function in any context, but it will always use binded context.`